# renaming columns after group by and sum in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

This is my group by command:

```
pdf_chart_data1 = pdf_chart_data.groupby('sell').value.agg(['sum']).rename(
    columns={'sum':'valuesum','sell' : 'selltime'}
)
```

I am able to change the column name for value but not for 'sell'.
Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You cannot rename it, because it is `index`. You can add `as_index=False` for return `DataFrame` or add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
pdf_chart_data1=pdf_chart_data.groupby('sell', as_index=False)['value'].sum()
                              .rename(columns={'sum':'valuesum','sell' : 'selltime'})
```

Or:

```
pdf_chart_data1=pdf_chart_data.groupby('sell')['value'].sum()
                          .reset_index()
                          .rename(columns={'sum':'valuesum','sell' : 'selltime'})
```

Comment: But the displayed result differs from the original. Meaning, the column grouped will show just once in the original, where as in your solution, it shows up in each row.

Comment: @kingmakerking - It depends if use `.reset_index()` or not or `, as_index=False` of not for Dataframe or `Series` in output (for test remove `rename`)

Comment: df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg('count') is my original query. When I run this, each col1 --> multiple col2 and count of each col2 is shown.

But, when I tinker with index as per your solution, col1 is shown each time col2 is shown.

Comment: @kingmakerking - In your solution missing `value` after `groupby`

Comment: Just groupby and count (https://privatty.com/en/n/JMpKJzsj#b32XLD5wi8t), same query with index false (https://privatty.com/en/n/o0ffPq0ZL#MEyQJiMhyw9).. and adding colname after groupby (https://privatty.com/en/n/9f32LpQA#eDW02MEZWbAq)> all have different styles of display (HTML). I need rename but display like first one.

Comment: @kingmakerking - hmmm, why is not used `.count()` instead `.agg('count')` ? Another thing, not sure how looks expcted output without data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227280/discussion-between-kingmakerking-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 4):

```
df = df.groupby('col1')['col1'].count()
df1= df.to_frame().rename(columns={'col1':'new_name'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Or shorter: `col1='col_name'; df.groupby(col1)[[col1]].count().rename(columns={col1:'Count'})`

Answer (score 0):

If you join to groupby with the same index where one is nunique ->number of unique items and one is unique->list of unique items then you get two columns called Sport.  Using as_index=False I was able to rename the second Sport name using rename then concat the two lists together and sort descending on sport and display the 10 five sportcounts.

```
 grouped=df.groupby('NOC', as_index=False)
 Nsport=grouped['Sport'].nunique()\
     .rename(columns={'Sport':'SportCount'})
 Nsport=Nsport.set_index('NOC')

 country_grouped=df.groupby('NOC')
 Nsport2=country_grouped['Sport'].unique()

 df2=pd.concat([Nsport,Nsport2],  join='inner',axis=1).reindex(Nsport.index)
df2=df2.sort_values(by=["SportCount"],ascending=False)


print(df2.columns)
for key,item in df2.head(5).iterrows():
   print(key,item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The super fast way

```
df = df.groupby('col1')['col1'].count() # returns a series which has a name
df1= df.to_frame('new_name') # <- overwrites the name of the series
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using the `rename` function, we can rename directly the output of the groupby in the `apply` function:

```
df.groupby("sell", as_index=False).apply(lambda g: pd.Series({"valuesum": g["value"].sum()}))
```