# Average Sales by Company

Tags: python, dataframe, average

Say my data frame is defined by-

```
dic = {'Company':['MCD','MCD','WND','BK','CFA','MCD','BK',
                    'WND','MCD','CFA','CFA','BK','WND','WND','MCD'],
       'Sales':[124.56,845.21,45.36,9.11,888.40,94.23,647.10,85.11,632.74,100.00,
                201.54,13.19,284.67,618.46,20.55]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(df)
```

and my output is-

```
   Company   Sales
0      MCD  124.56
1      MCD  845.21
2      WND   45.36
3       BK    9.11
4      CFA  888.40
5      MCD   94.23
6       BK  647.10
7      WND   85.11
8      MCD  632.74
9      CFA  100.00
10     CFA  201.54
11      BK   13.19
12     WND  284.67
13     WND  618.46
14     MCD   20.55
```

What I want to do is find out how much each company makes on average per sale

Desired output-

```
   Company Average_Sale
0      MCD            x
1      WND            x
2      CFA            x
3       BK            x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way,

```
df.groupby(['Company'])['Sales'].mean()
```

Comment: Say I wanted to make a new column for the averages. Would df['new_col']=df.groupby(['Company'])['Sales'].mean() work?

Comment: You can do this way, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416348/1138192

Answer (score 2):

This is done via `groupby` and `mean` as follows:

```
df.groupby(['Company']).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in pandas.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby("Company").mean()
grouped_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
grouped_df
```

output is:

[image]